# Python, TypeError:string argument without an encoding

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I need some help with this.. for some reason it keeps showing the typeError:string argument without an encoding,

```
sent_message = network_connect_join.send(bytes(sending_message)).encode('utf-8')
```

Its a snippet of the code, the next line just prints out normal messages

Answer (score 0):

`bytes()` requires two arguments when dealing with strings: a string to convert to bytes, and an encoding to use. Use `bytes(sending_message, 'utf-8')` instead.